# Necessity of static cache for mysql queries?

Tags: mysql, database, caching

This seems to be a clear issue; but I was unable to find an explicit answer. Consider a simple mysql database with indexed ID; without any complicated process. Just reading a row with WHERE clause. Does it really need to be cached? Reducing mysql queries apparently satisfies every one. But I tested reading a text from a flat cache file and by mysql query in a for loop of 1 - 100,000 cycles. Reading from flat file was only 1-2 times faster (but needed double memory). The CPU usage (by rough estimate from top in SSH) was almost the same.

Now I do not see any reason for using flat file cache. Am I right? or the case is different in long term? What may make slow query in such a simple system? Is it still useful to reduce mysql queries?

P.S. I do not discuss internal QC or systems like memcached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is depending of how you see the problem.

- There is a limit on number of mysql connection can be established at any one time.
  Holding the mysql connection resources in a busy site could lead to max connection error.
- Establish a connection to mysql via TCP is a resource eater (if your database is sitting in different server). In this case, access a local disk file will be much faster.
- If your server is located outside the network, the cost of physical distance will be heavier.
- If records are updated once daily, stored into cache is truly request once and reused for the day.

Comment: The point is that I am talking about a simple system without long queries. The lenght of mysql connection to read a row is only few milliseconds. Thus, even for busy websites it will not lead to high number of concurrent connections.

Comment: `Thus, even for busy websites it will not lead to high number of concurrent connections` this is a false assumption. No matter how simple query is that, there will still having overhead to connect database.